# android cursor adapter list view

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a view with a button and a list view backed by a cursor adapter containing bindView() and newView() for customized views. Each row of a list contains a Text and  a checkbox. The data for each view comes from the database. I'm passing my Database adapter in the cursor adapter constructor. This I use to update the database when a checkbox is check or unchecked (works well). Of course I run "re-query" on cursor and view.refreshDrawableState()). Is this a good idea? What would be a better solution?

Second problem more serious, when a Button is clicked it starts a new activity. After hitting the back button from the new activity I get back my list View. But when I try to click on the checkbox this time I get Database close exception. Why? How do I fix this error?

Following is the list view and code snippet.

---

```
        Button           --------> Starts a new activity
```

---

CheckBox   |   TextView

---

CheckBox   |   TextView

---

MyActivity.java

---

```
onCreate() {
    ...
    Button add_item_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_item_btn_id);
    add_item_btn.setOnclickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      //Start a new activity
    });
}

protected void onPause() {
   adapter.close();
   mCursor.close();
}

protected void onResume() {
  mListView = getListView();
  adapter = new DBAdapter(getApplication());
  adapter.open();
  mCursor = adapter.getAllItems();
  mCustomAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, mCursor, adapter);
  mListView.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter); 
}
```

### MyCursorAdapter.java

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
  Cursor mCursor;
  DBAdapter adapter;
  public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, DBAdapter _adapter)  {
    ...
    mCursor = c;
    adapter = _adapter;
  }

public void bindView(final View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

  final CheckBox itemStatusCB = (CheckBox) 
  view.findViewById(R.id.item_status_id);

  idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(myItem.ITEM_STATUS);
  final long itemStatus = cursor.getLong(idx);

  if (itemStatus == 1) {
     itemStatusCB.setChecked(true);           
  } else {
     itemStatusCB.setChecked(false);           
  }

  itemStatusCB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override public void onClick(View v) {
       int newStatus = 0;  
       if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
         newStatus = 1; 
       }
         adapter.updateItemStatus(itemId, newStatus);
         mCursor.requery();                           
         view.refreshDrawableState();
     });
  }
```

}
}

Comment: can you post code? and maybe it would help to ask your 2 questions separately since they do not appear to be related

Comment: Jim, Added code snippets.

Comment: you don't appear to be resetting your listview adapter in onResume - do you have an old reference?

Comment: Jim, Sorry, I missed that line. I've mListView.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter); in the resume. See updated code.

Comment: Your DBAdapter code also... your "requery" is fine (to answer that question). The "closed" database probably means your adapter is holding a reference to the db even after you re-create the object...

Comment: How do I fix this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: post stacktrace and more code

Comment: There is no more code to show, this is it. But I'll update the stack trace soon.

Comment: 06-23 21:59:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):   java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
    06-23 21:59:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQL\
iteDatabase.java:1702)
    06-23 21:59:07.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.ja\
va:1656)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. The new activity which was called had a DB connection open on onStart() and DB close on onDestroy(). After returning from that activity I was getting Database Illegal state Exception error as described with stack trace. I think it was returning cached version of DB connection. Once I removed DB.close() from the guest activity, it stopped issuing database not open error. Normally you would think that every activity can open a DB connection in it's onResume() or onStart() and close it in it's onPause() or onStop() or onDestroy() and it won't affect the connection across activities. Does this Make sense?